# Linking a sharepoint list to an external js file?

Tags: js

I would like the contents of searchStrings to refer to a list on sharepoint. Is there anyway to do that?

```
     document.getElementById('spe').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      var kitten = document.getElementById('spe').value;
      kitten = kitten.toLowerCase();
      var searchStrings = ['qwe', 'americredit', 'bay view', 'nationwide 
      equ', 
     'the moss ', 'kurt gei', 'haier', 'objekts'];
      for (var i = 0; i < searchStrings.length; i++) {
        if (kitten.search(searchStrings[i]) !== -1) {
          alert('potential watchlist');
        }
      }

  document.getElementById('spe').value = kitten;
   }, false);
```